# Rendering images from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, activeresource

The products API gives me **name, price, and images** keys. It's easy to display name and price since they are not nested. However, to display **images**, I have to target their **urls** which are nested. How can I display these images? They have a normal url, it's just I do not know how to target them.

Displaying the API

```
table.table.table-condensed
        thead
          tr
            th Name
            th Price
            th Image
        tbody
          - @products.each do |product|
            tr
              td= product.name
              td= product.price
              td #display images here
```

I use ActiveResource.

Can somebody help? I'm pretty stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over image objects use `each` method:

```
- product.images.each do |image|
  = image_tag image.url
```